# Error in converting weighted edgelist to adjecency matrix

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I want to create matrix from weighted edgelist. The weighted edgelist looks like this:
  
[image]

 
The expected matrix would be:

[2 3 3 3]
[4 0 0 0]
But, I'm getting this matrix as output:
[image]


 Here is the code:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from networkx.algorithms.bipartite import biadjacency_matrix
from networkx.readwrite.edgelist import read_weighted_edgelist

G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist("C:\\Users\\Mandeep\\Desktop\\BE project\\del.txt",create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype = int)
mat=biadjacency_matrix(G, row_order=[1,2], column_order=[1,2,3,4], weight= 'weight', dtype=None, format='csr')
matrix_of_ratings=pd.DataFrame(mat.todense())
print(matrix_of_ratings)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) instead. So, you need to set `create_using=nx.DiGraph()`. Using your input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1,2], 'b':[1,2,3,4,1], 'weight':[2,3,3,3,4]})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='a', target='b', edge_attr='weight', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())

biadjacency_matrix(G, row_order=[1,2], 
                       column_order=[1,2,3,4], 
                       weight= 'weight').todense()

matrix([[2, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanx mate. It helped :)